# Explain Ezekiel 31:18 that implies that the trees of Eden went down to the world of the dead

Tags: genesis

In Ezekiel 31:18 Explain how and why the trees of Eden went down to the world of the dead.

> (NASB) “To which among the trees of Eden are you so alike in glory and
> greatness? Yet you will be brought down **with the trees of Eden to the
> earth beneath**; you will lie in the midst of the uncircumcised with
> those who were killed by the sword. This is Pharaoh and all his
> hordes!”’ declares the Lord GOD.”

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for joining the group and contributing a question.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Answer (score 1):

In the Book of Ezekiel, there are three passages describe a place call Eden;

1. Ezekiel 28:11-19 -

This passage prophesies the fall of Tyre and its king. The Lord describes the king as "the seal of perfection, full of wisdom and perfect in beauty". The king is depicted as having been in **Eden**, the garden of God; adorned with precious stones. The king is mentioned being anointed as a guardian cherub, walking among the fiery stones on the holy mount of God. The description led some interpretations to view this king of Tyre as an allegory of Satan.

2. Ezekiel 31:1-18 -

In this prophecy concerning Egypt's downfall, the tallest tree symbolizes the strongest nation. The Lord reiterates the fall of Assyria, once the mightiest nation, described as a cedar in Lebanon (Eze 31:3). Therefore, the phrase "**all the trees of Eden in the garden of God**", refer to all nations. Since all nations reside on Earth, "Eden - the garden of God" likely symbolizes the earthly realm. In Ezekiel 31:16 & 31:18, **the trees of Eden** are mentioned again, with Egypt being one of the trees destined for downfall.

3. Ezekiel 36:33-36

This prophecy speaks of Israel restoration. The towns will be resettled; ruins rebuilt; and desolated land cultivated. The people who returned from exile will declare the once-wasted land has become like **the garden of Eden**".

Ezekiel's description of **'Eden'** differs from the garden that God created for Adam and Eve. Rather than a heavenly paradise, it appears to represent an earthly realm - a beautiful place fashioned by God for humanity. Egypt, once a marvel of the ancient world, is depicted as one of the tree within this symbolic Eden. However, the Lord's judgement has been pronounced upon Pharaoh and all his hordes, signaling their impending destruction.

Answer (score 1):

Ancient Hebrew scripture needs to be understood according to the literary devices the prophets employed. Take the poetic genre, for example. Ezekiel used that, as did many other writers. But in this day and age, some readers of scripture seem to think that every phrase must be taken literally.

Just this morning I was singing the words of Job set to metrical, poetic measure. Here is the perfect example for my answer. Most Bible-readers know the opening verse of chapter 14, *"Man, born of woman, is of few days, and full of trouble."* Not so many know the second verse: "He cometh forth like a flower, and is cut down. He fleeth like a shadow, and continueth not."

Notice the two different illustrations the writer uses? A flower, and a shadow. Is Job saying humans are flowers, or shadows? Of course not. A few verses on, Job uses ***a different illustration - that of trees***. In the sung lyrics it goes like this:

> "For of a tree there is some hope, if it should once be felled, that
> it will yet sprout up again, its branches' sap still held.
>
> Though in the earth its root wax old, its stock die in the ground;
> yet, scenting water, buds will sprout; plant-like, boughs shall
> abound.
>
> But man doth die and waste away; yea, man gives up his breath. Then
> where is he? Where has he gone? Can he be found in death?
>
> Until the heavens be no more, the grave their bed they'll make. Till
> then, they'll not be raised from sleep, nor shall they once awake."

Job was being poetic, comparing a dead tree with a dead man. There may be hope for a felled tree to sprout again, but not so with dead humans, 'felled' and fallen into the grave. He was also being prophetic, as was Ezekiel. Just read a few verses further on in chapter 14:

> "So man lieth down, and riseth not: till the heavens be no more, they
> shall not awake, nor be raised out of their sleep. O that thou woudest
> hide me in the grave, that thou wouldest keep me secret, until thy
> wrath be past, that thou wouldest appoint me a set time, and remember
> me. If a man die, shall he live again? All the days of my appointed
> time will I wait, till my change come. Thou shalt call, and I will
> answer thee. Thou wilt have a desire to the work of thine hands." Job
> 14:12-15 K.J.

The prophetic part of his poetic writing crops up again in chapter 19: he foretold the future time when his Redeemer would live and stand on the Earth, and even though Job's body had been eaten up by the worms, *"yet in my flesh shall I see God, whom I shall see for myself, and mine eyes shall behold, and not another."*

And, in the last prophetic book of the Bible - Revelation - we learn what Job anticipated - the day "when time shall be no more", the heavens and the earth departing as a scroll at the coming of the risen Redeemer who will usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment. Then Job will hear the call of his Redeemer and rise from the grave and see with new re-created eyes, his Redeemer.

Does this not **give the answer to all such questions about bits in the Bible that have been taken literally, instead of as poetic, prophetic statements** that the Holy Spirit inspired the writers to write?

Literal trees from the literal garden of Eden were not being said to have literally gone down to the earth below. The very part of the quotation - ***"This is Pharaoh and all his hordes!"*** - shows what the illustration was all about. Pharaoh never existed during the time of the garden of Eden, not for thousands of years later. The 'trees of Eden' was a sarcastic reference Ezekiel used to show up the vanity and pride of the mighty Pharaoh of his day who God would fell in one swoop, bringing Pharaoh into the grave. **Pharaoh was real, and literal. The 'trees of Eden' were not.**

Answer (score 0):

Trees do not have an afterlife, but they can indeed by brought down to Earth and return to the soil. The trees of Eden in Ezekiel are therefore literary devices that symbolize a lofty and glorified place. They eventually fall, as will the king of Egypt.

Ezekiel is apparently not thinking of the Tree of Life and the Tree of Knowledge. We know that the latter (if it was a literal tree rather than a symbol) was low enough that a human being could reach its fruit. The Tree of Life too could not be what Ezekiel refers to, because it is eternal; and it too is a fruit tree (according to the Book of Revelation) and therefore not of great height. Clearly he is thinking of towering trees that eventually die and return to the Earth.

No man lives in his physical body forever, even the Pharaoh, to whom this prophecy is directed.  So, like the trees of Eden, he will die. Whether he will lie in the underworld or "under the earth" (meaning the grave) is beside the point. The prophecy should be understood in the same vein as the "taunt" given by God to Isaiah and directed at the king of Babylon:

Isaiah 14

> 11 Your pomp is brought down to Sheol,
> the sound of your harps; maggots are the bed beneath you,
> and worms are your covering. 12 “How you are fallen from heaven,
> O Day Star, son of Dawn! How you are cut down to the ground,
> you who laid the nations low! 13 You said in your heart,
> ‘I will ascend to heaven; above the stars of God
> I will set my throne on high; I will sit on the mount of assembly
> in the far north; 14 I will ascend above the heights of the clouds,
> I will make myself like the Most High.’ 15 But you are brought down to Sheol,
> to the depths of the Pit.

Conclusion: The trees of Eden return to the Earth, and so will the king of Egypt. He may think he is a god, but he is a mortal man, just as the king of Babylon was. The prophecy is open to interpretation regarding whether he is doomed to lie in the ground, or to dwell in Sheol. But trees have no afterlife. So either way, the trees of Eden serve to exemplify the fact that even the loftiest beings are destined to die and decay.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the idea of Egypt as a tree descending into She'ol, the realm of the dead is stated several times in Eze 31:

- V14 - ... For they have all been consigned to death, to the depths of the earth, among the mortals who descend to the Pit.’
- V15 - This is what the Lord GOD says: ‘On the day it was brought down to She'ol, I caused mourning.
- V16a - I made the nations quake at the sound of its downfall, when I cast it down to She'ol with those who descend to the Pit.
- V16b - ... Then all the trees of Eden, the choicest and best of Lebanon, all the well-watered trees, were consoled in the earth below.
- V17 - They too descended with it to She'ol, to those slain by the sword.
- V18 - ... You also will be brought down to the depths of the earth to be with the trees of Eden.

We must recall that this is talking about the country of Egypt, a political entity, not a person.  In Eze 31 we have an extended metaphor where nations are compared to various trees metaphorically; specifically:

- Assyria is compared to a cedar of Lebanon; V3, 4
- Other nations are compared to "other trees of God" such as cedars, cypress and plane trees; V8, 9
- Egypt is compared to a very tall tree, greater than all other trees, etc; V5, 6, 10, 11, etc.

The cutting down of the tree representing Egypt is compared to the death of anything - it descends into the realm of the dead; V16.  That is all must eventually die and enter the realm of the dead.

Comment: the prophecy begins:  “Son of man, say to Pharaoh king of Egypt and to his multitude:
“Whom are you like in your greatness?
3     Behold, I will liken you to a cedar in Lebanon,
with fair branches and forest shade"

I would agree that the king of Egypt represents his country, but not that prophecy refers  "to a political entity, not a person."

Comment: @DanFefferman - Then what is V3 discussing?  I beg to differ - the prophecy is discussing the whole country's people, not an individual.  In in V2 it specifically says, "Pharaoh king of Egypt and to his multitude".  That is, not just Paharoah alone.  After all, what is a king without his kingdom?  We see the same in the OT where "Jacob" often means the entire nation of Israel.  Edom similarly.